# How to change class member value by pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, class-members

This function is part of a class called ClipInterface which provides a GUI 
to edit some member values from a given Clip object.

To a complish that, I am using this function that receives a Clip object
by pointer, and then it access to some of its members to modify them as follows:

```
void ClipInterface::update(Clip* _clip){
//p_clip is a pointer declared in the .h file so it can 
//work across the whole class

    p_clip = _clip;

    for (int i = 0; i < p_clip -> stepSequence.size(); ++i){
        stepToggles[i] -> active = p_clip -> stepSequence[i];        
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < p_clip -> stepSequence.size(); ++i){
        *p_clip -> stepSequence[i] = stepToggles[i] -> active;
    }
}
```

By using the previous expression, the program compiles but then it gives me a segmentation fault error when i try tu run it.

**The questions are:**

- how do i modify a class member value by pointer? i tried what  is
  here but i get a segmentation fault.
- what in this expresion y causing the segmentation fault?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Recall, `->` acts to dereference the pointer.

Comment: `*p_clip->stepSequence[i]` should be `p_clip->stepSequence[i]` (no `*`). You might also consider merging the 2 loops together into 1 loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*p_clip -> stepSequence[i] = stepToggles[i] -> active;
```

in here `p_clip` is already a pointer you should use;

```
p_clip -> stepSequence[i] = stepToggles[i] -> active;
```

To access members of a structure through a pointer, use the arrow operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either one of these

```
(*p_clip).stepSequences[i] = stepToggle
```

Where you first derefrence the pointer to get the object then get the member

Or use the arrow operator which is equivalent and have the same effect

```
p_clip->stepSequences[i] = stepToggle
```